# I need to export the results of this script to a .CSV but it will not work properly with Export-CSV cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I need to export the results of this script to a .CSV but it will not work properly with Export-CSV cmdlet

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' -Properties Name| Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Property Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address    

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)  
{ 

   Write-Host $Computer.Name
   Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Computer.Name | select Name, Version, Vendor, Caption | Sort-Object -Property Name,Vendor,Version,Caption

   Write-Host " "
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow !
What error do you have ? Can you provide the expected output, and the current one ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your issue lies when you use Name as the only Property in Get-ADComputer parameters.

Further I am not sure the syntax in your Get-WmiObject is fully correct.

Try this:  It will allow all the properties to return before you sort by name and subsequently select the properties you want to use.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem like "server" -and Enabled -eq "True"' -Properties * | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion, IPv4Address |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $_.Name |
        Sort-Object -Property Name,Vendor,Version,Caption | 
        Select-Object | -Property Name, Version, Vendor, Caption
    }

$Computers | Export-CSV -Path 'D:foo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows 10, Server 2016 and Server 2019.
The product class is correct and so are the fields.
It appears to hang but the reality it's just slow.
2-3 minutes per server is typical.

The article from Microsoft that documents this WMI class can be found here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394378(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiwL8.png)

All you have to do is add **Export-Csv** at the end of your pipeline:

```
get-wmiobject -Class win32_product |select Name, Version, Vendor, Caption|Export-Csv installedProducts.csv -Append
```

The *-Append* switch is important so you won't lose the output on your previous servers.

Note that sorting by name is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: How would i go about getting it separated by system name? I have an abundance of servers that this will be compiling data for.

Comment: Would not the first Write-Host in the loop do just that?